# Used vgextend/lvextend to add addtional 8GB space but it is not reflected in df output

Tags: virtualbox, lvm, ubuntu-12.04

I have created an instance of ubuntu VM in VirtualBox. At the beginning I have only allocated 7GB for the storage and the VM has now run out of space.

First I added another 8GB (/dev/sdb) to the VM via VirtualBox frontend. I then set up the following partitions:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
40 heads, 1 sectors/track, 419430 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x076b5690

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    16777215     8387584    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5            4096    16777215     8386560   8e  Linux LVM
```

Then I ran the following commands to expand the VG.

```
  sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb5
  sudo vgextend ubuntudevbox2 /dev/sdb5
  sudo lvextend 100% /dev/ubuntudevbox2/root
  lvextend --help
  sudo lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/ubuntudevbox2/root
  sudo lvextend -r -l 100%FREE /dev/ubuntudevbox2/root
  sudo resize2fs  /dev/mapper/ubuntudevbox2-root
```

I would have expected the size of / to expand to 16Gb. However df reports that

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntudevbox2-root  8.0G  6.9G  680M  92% /
```

the root mount has only increased to 8G

Here is the VG information

```
$ sudo vgdisplay ubuntudevbox2
[sudo] password for antkong: 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntudevbox2
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               15.75 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              4033
  Alloc PE / Size       2182 / 8.52 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       1851 / 7.23 GiB
  VG UUID               ZV6VAi-qkxC-KnKz-1LHg-nfLB-afSI-mVpIPv
```

Why I did not get the full 8Gb additional space?

Additional information 1: I have run `mkfs -t ext5 /dev/sdb5` right after using fdisk to add new partition. Can it cause the failure?

Additional information 2:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntudevbox2 3.5.0-27-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 19:58:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lvdisplay output:

$ sudo lvdisplay

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntudevbox2/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntudevbox2
  LV UUID                V1Qq0f-qKJR-UTf5-4tjM-ycoY-1J5L-mJQ2Fy
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntudevbox2, 2013-03-29 12:18:26 +1100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                8.03 GiB
  Current LE             2055
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntudevbox2/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntudevbox2
  LV UUID                LbvPFE-j3GO-oaF1-HQV3-a2r5-HTfy-YrhQve
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntudevbox2, 2013-03-29 12:18:29 +1100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                508.00 MiB
  Current LE             127
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

Comment: What is output of `lvdisplay`?

Comment: Output is added to the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Output is absolute in the line

```
sudo lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/ubuntudevbox2/root
```

Since you only had 8G of free extents after you vgextended you only get a lv representing that absolute size of 8G.

You must inform LVM you intend to make an *additional* space size. From the manpage of `lvextend`;

```
   -l, --extents [+]LogicalExtentsNumber[%{VG|LV|PVS|FREE|ORIGIN}]
          Extend  or  set  the  logical  volume  size  in units of logical
          extents.  With the '+' sign the value is  added  to  the  actual
          size of the logical volume and without it, the value is taken as
          an absolute one.
```

Try

```
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntudevbox2/root
```

Comment: @mlfe I ran it and then `sudo resize2fs  /dev/mapper/ubuntudevbox2-root` again. I can now see all the space I have allocated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from your `vgdisplay` output only about a half of space is allocated:

```
Alloc PE / Size       2182 / 8.52 GiB
Free  PE / Size       1851 / 7.23 GiB
```

I suspect you need to specify parameters for `lvextend` more explicitly.

Comment: Agree with your diagnosis.  It's difficult to debug exactly; the lvextend command-line given doesn't seem to work on my test box (debian testing).  `sudo lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_brick-lv_TEST` seemed to work fine for me.  Specifying it in PEs would be a reasonable alternative tho.  It's almost as if the command used was more like `lvextend -l 100%LV`.  Though that should have been obvious - it told me `New size (1 extents) matches existing size (1 extents)
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.`.

Comment: @alexd @sourcejedi I have updated the question with all the lvextend I ran. Indeed the original one did not work. Eventually I ran `lvextend -r -l 100%FREE /dev/ubuntudevbox2/root`.